# Logout button not rendered

Tags: support, login

To be able to chat I need to logout and login again as the credentials given are too old. However I can't find a logout button:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: I have same issue, raised a new question.  (Works fine in 11.10, but not with **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** (64bit) and Firefox 12.0).

Comment: See: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3260/no-user-page-no-logout-firefox-12-on-ubuntu-12-04-64bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visit your user page, and click logout there.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

[image]